# Windows Authentication C# MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication

Is it possible to have automatic user authentication from Active Directory when open Internet Explorer without user enter username/password.

As right now. I have windows authentication, where users after open internet explorer, they have to enter he/she username and password from AD. So since the application has the same credential that the PC. I was wondering, how could i do so user don't have to log in when open internet explorer to use the web application.

I am thinking something like single sign on type of deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your users already log in with their AD credentials your problem is almost resolved.
Your users have to add the site to the local intranet zone (so they aren't prompted for credentials) in their Interner Explorer Configuration. Also check in internet explorer security zone settigns that the following is enabled:

User Authentication -> Set Automating Logon Only In Intranet Zone

Comment: Is there any way i can do that from the server side... I don't want to users to do anything.